# Combining observations with different time scales (e.g., hourly counts with daily weather)

Tags: r, datetime, tidyverse

I have a data set that has daily means of weather variables and a second set that has hourly counts of animal observations. I want to combine these datasets so that I can build a model evaluating mixed effect of weather variables on counts. To make things just a bit more complicated, the data formats are different with observations having a separate column for month, day, and hour and the weather starting with a single Dd/M/-yyyy HH:mm column. I could hand fix this in the raw data for the observations if necessary.

How do I do this best in R? Sample data:

```
date <- c("1/1/2020 3:00", "1/2/2020 3:00","1/3/2020 3:00")
temp <- c(18, 25, 10)
press <- c(.25, .5, 1.25)
met <- data.frame(date, press, temp)

month <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
day <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3,3)
hour <- c(10, 11, 12, 10, 11, 12,10, 11, 12)
obs <- c( 14, 88, 67, 198, 3, 54, 2, 80, 36)
counts <- data.frame(month, day, hour, obs)
```

Comment: (1) `counts` has no year, should we assume it to be 2020? (2) Are `mets` date in `m/d/Y` or `d/m/Y` format? (3) What is your expected output? A join of this will produce four columns (date, temp, press, obs), and since none of the times match, each row either have both temp and press (and `NA` for obs) or vice versa, no row will have all three.

Comment: Desired output is a sf with same rows as count dd plus temp press data added as columns. Trick is since there's only one temp observation per day but 3 counts,  how do I smear the temp data across the hours? Or put another way,  I want to add rows in the Count df for the Met observations (e.g., for Jan, 1 all three hours have the Met data for that day since its av daily mean.

Comment: Please provide a literal sample output frame just as you gave input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited to spread a daily observation across all hours.

Here's some code using `dplyr` and `lubridate`. The function `mutate` creates new columns in the data frames, `parse_date_time` creates an object with a data time class and `floor_date` finds the day when the observation happened.

The functions `group_by` and `summarise` combine observations to create a mean for a given day.

The two are combined using `inner_join`.

I've assumed 2020.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

date <- c("1/1/2020 3:00", "1/2/2020 3:00","1/3/2020 3:00")
temp <- c(18, 25, 10)
press <- c(.25, .5, 1.25)
met <- 
    data.frame(date, press, temp) %>% 
    mutate(dmyhm = parse_date_time(date, orders='m/d/y H:M')) %>%
    mutate(ymd = floor_date(dmyhm, unit = 'day')) %>%
    select(ymd, press, temp)

month <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
day <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3,3)
hour <- c(10, 11, 12, 10, 11, 12,10, 11, 12)
obs <- c( 14, 88, 67, 198, 3, 54, 2, 80, 36)
counts <- 
    data.frame(month, day, hour, obs) %>% 
    mutate(dmyhm = parse_date_time(paste0(month, '/', day, '/', '2020 ', hour), orders='m/d/y H')) %>%
    mutate(ymd = floor_date(dmyhm, unit='day')) 

# a full join causes extra rows to be added where they 
# don't exist in the smaller data set

combined <- 
    counts %>% 
    full_join(met, by = 'ymd') %>%
    select(month, day, hour, obs, press, temp)

combined
#   month day hour obs press temp
#   1     1   1   10  14  0.25   18
#   2     1   1   11  88  0.25   18
#   3     1   1   12  67  0.25   18
#   4     1   2   10 198  0.50   25
#   5     1   2   11   3  0.50   25
#   6     1   2   12  54  0.50   25
#   7     1   3   10   2  1.25   10
#   8     1   3   11  80  1.25   10
#   9     1   3   12  36  1.25   10
```

Comment: I do not want to mean count bservations but rather add the correct met observations (time, press) to each hour row. Does that make sense?

Comment: Answer updated with new information.

Comment: While the code is definitive, perhaps adjusting the descriptive to reflect the `full_join` eventually used.

Comment: added some comments

Comment: @AndrewChisholm This is great but in my desire to simplify the problem, I oversimplified and am having trouble adding this to my workflow. E.g., I am importing CSVs and editing them prior to trying to add the exisitng dfs together. I'd like to add my specific code and examples from my dataset - should I edit the original question or create a new question and link it here?

Comment: Editing the question risks a long dialogue with multiple questions being asked which will risk the question being closed. It already has one vote to close. If the original question has been answered, accept it and ask another.